# Custom field as meta description

Tags: custom-field, wp-head

I want to make a description input field inside the normal post adding page (in the dashboard) so each time I'm posting something I'll be able to handle the description as I like. Then I would target this name field to add something like this inside my header:

```
echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $mycustomfield . '" />' . "\n";
```

So at the end it would look like this (correct me if needed):

```
function mycustomdescription() {
   global $post;
   if ( is_single() ) {
      echo '<meta name="description" content="' . $mycustomfield . '" />' . "\n";
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mycustomdescription' , 2 );
```

How do I do this in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch the data from a custom field named `wpse_desc`:

[image: custom field]

then here's one way to do that with your code snippet:

```
function wpse_custom_meta_description() 
{
    // Nothing to do
    if ( ! is_single() )
        return;

    // Fetch our custom field value
    $desc = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'wpse_desc', true );

    // Output
    if( ! empty( $desc ) )
        printf( 
            '<meta name="description" content="%s" />',
            esc_attr( trim( $desc ) )
        );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_custom_meta_description' , 2 );
```

It's important to escape the value of the content attribute, because you don't want e.g.  authors of your site to be able to write something like:

```
><script>alert('Hello World!');</script><
```

We might also want to strip the tags out with [`wp_strip_all_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/) and limit the word count with [`wp_trim_words()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/), that also uses `wp_strip_all_tags()`, but we should keep in mind that it would still allow very long words. If you need a maximum length, then you might need to look further into that, I'm sure there are various approaches out there.

Here we prefix the custom field name with the `wpse_` prefix, to avoid possible name collisions.

Hope you can adjust it to your needs, like using post excerpt or post content  fallbacks.

Comment: Thanks, birgire! But can you explain me something... Does this mean the `$desc` will be outputted outside the `meta` tag `>`?  And one more thing, how do I actually put the `input` field inside the dashboard? what should I use

Comment: And thank you for alerting me about the escaping value of the content!

Comment: Omg! Silly me... THANK YOU, Birgire! Very, very much for the help!

Comment: Here we use the custom field support of the post post type. So you can add a new custom field named `wpse_desc` (I added a screenshot). The custom field value will be inserted as the meta description value inside the `<head>` tag..  @wootopia

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation! I also wasn't aware about "Custom Fields", so in case someone will have problem with it, here's the link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Custom_Fields

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the link. I updated the answer with functions that can be used to strip out the tags and limit the word count. @wootopia

Comment: Thank you once again! :) This is extremely interesting and useful!

Comment: does this function need caching modifications if used in very large number of posts ?

Comment: To answer that it's best to profile it. But I think something else than this would start to give problems during high page load. Meta queries that search for string values are the one that we should worry about, that's not the case here @JoannaMikalai